# Pip install upgrade unable to remove temp files

Tags: python, permissions, pip

In the course of maintaining a CLI utility, I want to add an `update` action that will grab the latest version of that package from PyPI and upgrade the existing installation.

```
$ cli -V
1.0.23

$ cli update
// many lines of pip spam

$ cli -V
1.0.24  // or etc
```

This is working perfectly on all machines that have Python installed system-wide (in `C:\Python36` or similar), but machines that have Python installed as a user (in `C:\users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36`) receive this error as the old version is uninstalled:

```
Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'C:\\Users\\username\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-uninstall-f5a7rk2y\\cli.exe'
Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.
```

I had assumed that this is due to the fact that the `cli.exe` called out in the error text is currently running when pip tries to remove it, however the path here is not to `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Programs\Python\Python36\Scripts` where that exe lives, but instead to `%TEMP%`. How is it allowed to move the file there, but not remove it once it's there?

including `--user` in the install args as recommended by the error message does ***not*** (contrary to the indication of an earlier edit of this question) resolve the issue, but moving the `cli` executable elsewhere does.

I'm hoping for an answer that:

1. Explains the underlying issue of failing to delete the executable from the TEMP directory, and...
2. Provides a solution to the issue, either to bypass the permissions error, or to query to see if this package is installed as a user so the code can add `--user` to the args.

While the question is fairly general, a MCVE is below:

```
def update(piphost):
    args = ['pip', 'install',
        '--index-url', piphost,
        '-U', 'cli']
    subprocess.check_call(args)

update('https://mypypiserver:8001')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As originally surmised, the issue here was trying to delete a running executable. Windows isn't a fan of that sort of nonsense, and throws `PermissionErrors` when you try. Curiously though, you can definitely *rename* a running executable, and in fact several [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7198666/strategies-for-replacing-program-executable-in-windows) [from](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3365347/how-can-we-overwrite-exe-files-while-users-are-running-them) [different](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/799656/renaming-a-running-process-file-image-on-windows) [tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9162969/how-can-a-c-binary-replace-itself) use this fact to allow an apparent change to a running executable.

This also explains why the executable appeared to be running from `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Programs\Python\Python36\Scripts` but failing to delete from `%TEMP%`. It has been renamed (moved) to the `%TEMP%` folder during execution (which is legal) and then pip attempts to remove that directory, also removing that file (which is illegal).

The implementation goes like so:

1. Rename the current executable (`Path(sys.argv[0]).with_suffix('.exe')`)
2. `pip install` to update the package
3. Add logic to your entrypoint that deletes the renamed executable if it exists.

```py
import click  # I'm using click for my CLI, but YMMV
from pathlib import Path
from sys import argv

def entrypoint():
    # setup.py's console_scripts points cli.exe to here

    tmp_exe_path = Path(argv[0]).with_suffix('.tmp')
    try:
        tmp_exe_path.unlink()
    except FileNotFoundError:
        pass
    return cli_root

@click.group()
def cli_root():
    pass

def update(pip_host):

    exe_path = Path(argv[0])
    tmp_exe_path = exe_path.with_suffix('.tmp')
    handle_renames = False
    if exe_path.with_suffix('.exe').exists():
        # we're running on Windows, so we have to deal with this tomfoolery.
        handle_renames = True
        exe_path.rename(tmp_exe_path)
    args = ['pip', 'install',
        '--index-url', piphost,
        '-U', 'cli']
    try:
        subprocess.check_call(args)
    except Exception:  # in real code you should probably break these out to handle stuff
        if handle_renames:
            tmp_exe_path.rename(exe_path)  # undo the rename if we haven't updated

@cli_root.command('update')
@click.option("--host", default='https://mypypiserver:8001')
def cli_update(host):
    update(host)
```

Answer (score 0):

Great solution provided by the previous commenter: [Pip install upgrade unable to remove temp files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55817697/pip-install-upgrade-unable-to-remove-temp-files/55824310#55824310) by https://stackoverflow.com/users/3058609/adam-smith

I want to add to remarks that made the code work for me (using python 3.8):

- Missing parentheses for the return of the entrypoint function (however, the function I'm pointing to is not decorated with `@click.group()` so not sure if that's the reason)

```
def entrypoint():
    # setup.py's console_scripts points cli.exe to here

    tmp_exe_path = Path(argv[0]).with_suffix('.tmp')
    try:
        tmp_exe_path.unlink()
    except FileNotFoundError:
        pass
>>> return cli_root() <<<
```

- Missing `with_suffix('.exe')` when attempting the rename in the update function. If I use the original code I get `FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: '..\..\..\updater' -> '..\..\..\updater.tmp'`

```
def update(pip_host):

    exe_path = Path(argv[0])
    tmp_exe_path = exe_path.with_suffix('.tmp')
    handle_renames = False
    if exe_path.with_suffix('.exe').exists():
        # we're running on Windows, so we have to deal with this tomfoolery.
        handle_renames = True
>>>     exe_path.with_suffix('.exe').rename(tmp_exe_path)    <<<
        
        ...
```

Comment: Yeah using `click` the entrypoint is expected to be a cli.group, which is why I returned the decorated function. On Windows you'll have to add a bit more than this to make it bulletproof. Recall that anything in `%PATHEXT%` can be executed without using its suffix, so your code should try `my_path=Path(argv[0]); exe_path = next((p := my_path.with_suffix(suffix) for suffix in map(str.strip, os.getenv("PATHEXT").split(';')) if p.exists())`